# Help with updating an app on app store

Tags: xcode, app-store, version

What should I change in info.plist when updating an app?

I see that there are:
Bundle version string, short: 1.0
and
Bundle version: 1.0

Should I change both to 1.1 or just one of them and which?

Answer (score 2):

Both.

- `Bundle version` is supposed to be a `double` (eg. 1.0, 1.01, 2.1).
- `Bundle version string, short` needs to be a `string` (eg. 1.0r1, 1.01b1401, 2.1a);

So, in this case you probably just want to adjust them to 1.1.

**Note that** AFAIK, Apple only looks at `Bundle version` and compares it with the previous bundle (which will lead to a rejection if you're new `Bundle version` <= old `Bundle version`). You're fully responsible for updating the `Bundle version string, short` yourself!